# Values not showing -- embedded ruby within innerHTML of anchor tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, embedded-ruby

I have an embedded ruby layout file for a navbar. The innerHTML of the anchor tag holds an embedded ruby snippet calling the value of the string.

```
<% text_var = "check string" %>
<a id="show_string" class="brand" ><% text_var %></a>
```

**RESULTS**

- Blank title for anchor tag
- Rails did not throw an error page

---

If I have instead `<a id="show_string" class="brand" >This is Plain Text</a>` then it displays "This is Plain Text" as the title of the anchor tag.

- Is there a conflict with the embedded ruby and the innerHTML?
- Syntax / Use of embedded ruby incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<a id="show_string" class="brand" ><%= text_var %></a>
```

You need the = sign to display the string

Comment: Thanks. What are the purposes of that operator `<%=` vs `<%`

Comment: @MattClendenen: `<%= x %>` is for interpolation (i.e. `x` goes into the HTML) whereas `<% ... %>` is just used to evaluate some Ruby code.